collect2.exe: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' (using MSYS2 with VSCode on Windows)
I'm trying to compile a C++ program on Windows using g++ installed via MSYS2 in Visual Studio Code (VSCode), but I'm encountering a linker error.
Here is the version of gcc and g++ and gdb
My question:
How can I resolve this error while working in VSCode? Is there something wrong with my MSYS2 or VSCode configuration, or is there an additional step I might be missing to ensure ld is properly recognized?
Any help would be appreciated!
I'm trying to compile a C++ program on Windows using g++ installed via MSYS2 in Visual Studio Code (VSCode), but I'm encountering a linker error.

Seems hard to believe that you installed g++ without also installing ld, so the first thing to work out is whether you have ld installed or not. What happens if you try the command which ld?

The official guide is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw  (A much easier option is to use Visual Studio Community (not Code), which requires no manual configuration or extra downloads).

Might be a "PATH" issue. If you don't run in the right MSYS2 terminal, binaries for your tools can't be found. Yet you can append their location to your user path in order to get them reachable from any terminal, including vs-code embedded one. You must provide more details if you want a more precise answer

Open the msys2 terminal and see if you  can compile a "Hello World" application inside it. If that works the problem could be your PATH environment variable or possibly you have multiple incompatible versions of MinGW installed.
